# Preventing script execution and file downloads in a directory?

Tags: security, apache-httpd, php

I have a directory on my website where I'm storing files uploaded by users. I use a whitelist for uploaded file types and also save the files with hashed names, but from what I've read another good security precaution is to stop script execution in the directory. I also want to prevent files in the directory from being directly accessed since I don't want users to be able to download files that aren't theirs.

My server runs Linux with Apache. Is the following .htaccess file correct for what I'm trying to achieve?

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
<FilesMatch .php>
    SetHandler None
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
    Order allow, deny
    Deny from all
    php_admin_flag engine off
</Directory>
```

The first two directives [(`Order` and `Deny`)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html) (or [2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) or [2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html)) should prohibit anyone from accessing the directory via Apache (they will get a 403 error). The `php_admin_flag` turns off mod_php, which should actually be superfluous given the `Deny from all`.

Another approach, possibly superior, is to not have the directory under your web root at all.

Comment: Thanks! If I put that in a .htaccess file inside of the directory where the files are, should I change `path/to/dir` to just `/`?

Comment: @Nate if you use an htaccess file, you omit the `<Directory>` lines entirely. Make absolutely certain your upload script doesn't allow someone to upload a new `.htaccess`. (Also, you may have to use `php_flag` instead of `php_admin_flag` in an .htaccess)